ArcGIS Arcade Script - No Value Returned when using multiple intersect methods
In this original Arcade script below, room IDs are successfully pulled and populated in the 'room_id' field of a point asset based on the floor level polygon of the intersecting layer. In virtually all cases, a Room ID is returned when running this script. The original working script is as follows:
// Check the value of the room level field, values are "base" "lowr" "uppr" "pent" "mezz"
var roomlevel = $feature.floor_level

// Define a function to get the room ID based on the room level
function GetRoomIdByLevel(levelName) {
  // Create a feature set using the corresponding layer name
  var level = FeatureSetByName($map, "ORD_" + levelName)
  
  // Get the first intersecting room with the current location
  var intersectingRoom = First(Intersects($feature, level))
  
  // Check if an intersecting room is found (boolean check)
  if (intersectingRoom != null) {
    return intersectingRoom['room_id'];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// Get the room IDs for all levels
var baseRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Basement");
var lowerRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Lower");
var upperRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Upper");
var pentRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Penthouse");
var mezzRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Mezzanine");
var ringRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("RingTunnel");

// Return the room ID based on the room level
if (roomlevel == "base") {
  return baseRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "lowr") {
  return lowerRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "uppr") {
  return upperRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "pent") {
  return pentRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "mezz") {
  return mezzRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "ring") {
  return ringRoomId;
} else {
  // Return null if room level is invalid
  return null;
}


And here is the modified script below that adds 'Within' as intersect method 1 and places the original method as intersect method 2. The goal here is to use intersect method 2 as a backup in case intersect method 1 returns a null value. So far, we have been unsuccessful at getting this modified script to return a value in the Room ID field. As far as we can tell, the script is functional and not returning any errors.
// Check the value of the room level field, values are "base" "lowr" "uppr" "pent" "mezz"
var roomlevel = $feature.floor_level

// Define a function to get the room ID based on the room level
function GetRoomIdByLevel(levelName) {
  // Create a feature set using the corresponding layer name
  var level = FeatureSetByName($map, "ORD_" + levelName)
  
  // Get the first intersecting room with the current location
  var intersectingRoom1 = First(Within($feature, level))
  // Get the second intersecting room with the current location
  var intersectingRoom2 = First(Intersects($feature, level))
  
  // Check if an intersecting room is found (boolean check)
  if (intersectingRoom1 != null) {
    return intersectingRoom1['room_id'];
  } else if (intersectingRoom2 != null) {
    return intersectingRoom2['room_id'];
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

// Get the room IDs for all levels
var baseRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Basement");
var lowerRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Lower");
var upperRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Upper");
var pentRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Penthouse");
var mezzRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("Mezzanine");
var ringRoomId = GetRoomIdByLevel("RingTunnel");

// Return the room ID based on the room level
if (roomlevel == "base") {
  return baseRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "lowr") {
  return lowerRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "uppr") {
  return upperRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "pent") {
  return pentRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "mezz") {
  return mezzRoomId;
} else if (roomlevel == "ring") {
  return ringRoomId;
} else {
  // Return null if room level is invalid
  return null;
}


check if level is actually set.

What do you see when you use the Console function in various locations in your script? To see the results in the console, use the Run button in the Arcade editor
var level = FeatureSetByName($map, "ORD_" + levelName)
Console(level)
var intersectingRoom1 = First(Within($feature, level))
Console(intersectingRoom1)

The code works properly when I use it on two of my layers. It would always return the results of the Within function and not need to use the Intersects function, but I didn't have any features that weren't totally within the "level" features
If I'm interpreting your code correctly, you can simplify it like this
var level = Decode(
  $feature.floor_level, 
  "base", "Basement",
  "lowr", "Lower",
  "uppr", "Upper",
  "pent", "Penthouse",
  "mezz", "Mezzanine",
  "ring", "RingTunnel"
);

// Define a function to get the room ID based on the room level
function GetRoomIdByLevel(levelName) {
  // Create a feature set using the corresponding layer name
  var level = FeatureSetByName($map, "ORD_" + levelName);

  // Get the first intersecting room with the current location
  var intersectingRoom1 = First(Within($feature, level));
  if (intersectingRoom1 != null) return intersectingRoom1["room_id"];
  // Get the second intersecting room with the current location
  var intersectingRoom2 = First(Intersects($feature, level));
  if (intersectingRoom2 != null) return intersectingRoom2["room_id"];

  return null;
}

return GetRoomIdByLevel(level);


Thanks. I'll test it out and let you know what I find. The code you provided is much simpler and doesn't repeat itself on the If Then Else statements.

We got the 'intersectingRoom1' line of code to work on points that were touching or within the polygons, but we can't get the 'intersectingRoom2' line of code to work on point that are completely outside the polygons. Would a search distance parameter or buffer before the 'intersectingRoom2' line of code work here?

Yes, you'd have to create a buffer around the point and use that feature in the Intersection for any points that are completely outside the polygons.
